# recover Skype password from config.xml

Tags: skype

I have my skype username but no email and password.

I can find config.xml file in my App folder. How to recover password from config.xml or some other file?

Comment: Did you take a look here? http://insecurety.net/?p=427

Comment: How do I use this? It has a lot of explanation. Is there somewhere a short solution.

Comment: I'll add an explanation in a separate answer.

Comment: Using metasploit: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jE6XqycmAYo

Answer (score 1):

According to the following [article](http://web.archive.org/web/20151016181523/http://insecurety.net/?p=427):

If you have chosen to save your password you will have the following data in your `config.xml` file:

- The login MD5 hash
- The generated RSA private key
- The Skype encrypted corresponding RSA public key

Everything is heavily encrypted but symmetric.

If you want to break it you'll need to use some code written in the [article](http://web.archive.org/web/20151016181523/http://insecurety.net/?p=427), another option is to use the dedicated [metasploit](http://www.metasploit.com/) [module](https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/blob/master/modules/post/windows/gather/credentials/skype.rb).